# Error with calculations with offsets in vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, offset

I have created a macro to perform various calculations. However, at this part of the code, it says there is an error(object required) in the line

```
cell2.Value = cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value * cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value
```

I am providing the entire part of the code where this line belongs to:

```
For Each cell2 In Range("F2:F" & lastrow2)
If cell2.Offset(0, -3).Value = "ROMANIA" Then
cell2.Value = cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value / cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value
Else
cell2.Value = cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value * cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value
End If
Next cell2
```

Comment: FWIW - your code works for me.

Comment: I made a mistake with the lastrow2 as I set the value beforing filling up column A :p its working !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cell2       As Range
    Dim lastrow2    As Long
    Dim wks         As Worksheet

    lastrow2 = 55 'or calculated value

    Set wks = Worksheets("SomeName")

    For Each cell2 In wks.Range("F2:F" & lastrow2)
        If cell2.Offset(0, -3).Value = "ROMANIA" Then
            cell2.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-1]"
            'cell2.Formula = cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value / cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Else
            cell2.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2] * RC[-1]"
            'cell2.Formula = cell2.Offset(0, -2).Value * cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    Next cell2

End Sub
```

Build a few formulas in excel and use the macro recorder to see how they are translated to VBA.

Comment: shouldnt it be  cell2.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-1]"?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - I suppose it should.

Comment: Wasn't the second a multiplication?

Comment: @QHarr - yup, it was.

Comment: guys sorry to bother you again... I have an issue.. the first time I run it, it runs great.. if I try to run the file again, without closing it, then it wont work.. any ideas?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - can you try pressing F8 and see where it does not work?

Comment: it does not work on the lines where I have multiplications or divisions with offsets..

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - check again.